# Como usar CASE em uma clausula Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte situação de script:

```
SELECT *
FROM Formulario 
WHERE DataInclusao = '2019-10-28 08:19:54.000' 
AND chave = 'XXXXXXX' AND Id = 2
```

Essa tabela possui uma coluna chamada ProdutoId, na qual se essa consulta acima retornar a informação de ProdutoId diferente de nulo, preciso que seja incluído essa condição na consulta. Caso o contrario, o script permanece com as condições acima.

Tentei fazer das seguintes formas e não tive sucesso

```
SELECT *
FROM Formulario 
WHERE DataInclusao = '2019-10-28 08:19:54.000' 
AND chave = 'XXXXXXX' AND Id = 2
AND ProductId = (CASE WHEN ProductId IS NULL THEN IS NULL ELSE 150 END)
```

Mas nesse caso não retorna nada se for `AND ProductId = NULL` e sim `AND ProdutoId IS NULL`

Tentei utilizar IF depois de todos WHERE e nada funcionou;

Comment: No caso, a condição não seria `... AND (productid IS NULL OR productid = 150)`? Sem precisar ir ao `CASE WHEN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria essa condição usando **OR** ao invés de **CASE WHEN**.

Ficaria assim:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Formulario 
WHERE DataInclusao = '2019-10-28 08:19:54.000' 
AND chave = 'XXXXXXX' AND Id = 2
AND (ProductId IS NULL OR ProductId = 150)
```

Mas se quiser fazer com **CASE WHEN**, teria só que tratar os valores nulos dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Formulario 
WHERE DataInclusao = '2019-10-28 08:19:54.000' 
AND chave = 'XXXXXXX' AND Id = 2
AND ISNULL(ProductId, 0) = (CASE WHEN ProductId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 150 END)
```

Ou ainda poderia usar a clausula **IN**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Formulario 
WHERE DataInclusao = '2019-10-28 08:19:54.000' 
AND chave = 'XXXXXXX' AND Id = 2
AND ISNULL(ProductId, 0) IN (0, 150)
```

Comment: Obrigada Daniel.
Para resolver o problema utilizei a primeira sugestão do **OR**  `AND (ProductId IS NULL OR ProductId = 150)`